# How to force redownload with wget?

Tags: linux, command-line, wget

I had the bad surprise that wget doesn't redownload when a file of the same name already exist.

Is there an option to force him to redownload without deleting the file first on linux ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
wget -O - $url >/path/to-file
```

Or, if you are mirroring, you can use the `-c` flag. This will make it so the files are "continued", but since they're already at the size the server is telling wget, it will "continue" them from the beginning.

Comment: That's dash "capital letter O" for the confused.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot on what options you've given `wget` on the commandline.  I've found that the default behavior on my systems is to re-download, but append a number to the filename to make it different.

Here's the `--no-clobber` option description from `man wget` (for wget 1.11.4) -- note the interactions with other options, particularly `-r` and `-p`.  (Emphasis mine.)

> -nc
>    --no-clobber
>    If a file is downloaded more than once in the same directory, Wget’s
>    behavior depends on a few options, including -nc.  In certain cases, the
>    local file will be clobbered, or overwritten, upon repeated download.  In
>    other cases it will be preserved.
>
> **When running Wget without -N, -nc, -r, or p, downloading the same file in
>    the same directory will result in the original copy of file being preserved
>    and the second copy being named file.1.**  If that file is downloaded yet
>    again, the third copy will be named file.2, and so on.  When -nc is
>    specified, this behavior is suppressed, and Wget will refuse to download
>    newer copies of file.  Therefore, ""no-clobber"" is actually a misnomer in
>    this mode---it’s not clobbering that’s prevented (as the numeric suffixes
>    were already preventing clobbering), but rather the multiple version saving
>    that’s prevented.
>
> **When running Wget with -r or -p, but without -N or -nc, re-downloading a
>    file will result in the new copy simply overwriting the old.  Adding -nc
>    will prevent this behavior, instead causing the original version to be
>    preserved and any newer copies on the server to be ignored.**
>
> When running Wget with -N, with or without -r or -p, the decision as to
>    whether or not to download a newer copy of a file depends on the local and
>    remote timestamp and size of the file.  -nc may not be specified at the same
>    time as -N.
>
> Note that when -nc is specified, files with the suffixes .html or .htm will
>    be loaded from the local disk and parsed as if they had been retrieved from
>    the Web.

Answer (score -1):

This is controlled by the `-nc` or `--no-clobber` option.

It's complicated and depends on other options, but you have the choice of everwriting or renaming *redownloaded* files file.1, file.2

The man page seems to say that *if you don't use the 'no-clobber'* option, the redownloaded files will be renumbered. Do you see files with numeric suffixes?

In any case, see the `man page`